How can I configure Emacs to use ~/.config/emacs/init.el?
How can I configure Emacs to use ~/.config/emacs/init.el instead of Emacs creating a new .emacs.d directory for customization?
I want Emacs to utilize ~/.config/emacs/init.el for my configuration settings, however whenever I start Emacs, it keeps creating a new .emacs.d directory. How can I ensure that Emacs recognizes ~/.config/emacs/init.el as my configuration file location without generating a new .emacs.d directory?

You can, of course.

Emacs can also look in an XDG-compatible location for init.el, the default is the directory ~/.config/emacs.
This can be overridden by setting XDG_CONFIG_HOME in your environment, its value replaces ~/.config in the name of the default XDG init file.
However ~/.emacs.d, ~/.emacs, and ~/.emacs.el are always preferred if they exist, which means that you must delete or rename them in order to use
the XDG location.

Two suggestions:

Set the environment variable XDG_CONFIG_HOME=~/.config/.
Delete ~/.emacs.d, ~/.emacs, and ~/.emacs.el.

